# CSS bugs in Safari browser

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

To begin with, I just started my first job as a junior front-end developer and got a task to fix bugs in the safari browser. (Chrome works well).  Our web app is developed using TypeScript, React (with Material UI framework) and Webpack.

Unfortunately, I spent hours surfing the internet and trying to find a solution for these bugs, but I couldn’t. I feel these bugs come from Material UI, but I might be wrong. I hope someone can help me with that and thank you in advance!   So the main problems I encountered in Safari were kind of CSS bugs.  Take a look:

1. [Chrome_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlScK.png) / [Chrome_View_Wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEbC8.png)
2. [Safari_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aShVX.png) / [Safari_View_Wrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sFlD.png) (Bugs are marked)

As you can see the in Chrome everything looks okay, while in Safari some of the things get corrupted.

1. ToolBar items get wrapped even there is free space. You can take a look at [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XmTK.png) and [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGpq0.png). For example, if I comment (margin: -16px;) last item gets to its place.
2. Blue drawer background is not displayed until you wrap it out. You can take a look at [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqmZr.png) and [CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIctR.png). For example, if I comment (overflow-x: hidden;) it gets fixed.
3. Wrap button on click should transform its direction by 180 degrees.
4. Footer and Drawer do not display images.

If anyone is familiar with this kind of issues please share your experience.

P.s. It would be great to avoid putting everywhere prefixes manually.

Comment: You need to use prefix everywhere. That might be the problem (please provide us code instead of screenshots). Try this. : https://autoprefixer.github.io/ You can't work in CSS without using prefixes ! All browsers have different notation for each property

Comment: @ThéoBenoit shouldn't it be done by the Webpack automatically? As I understand Webpack generates bundles that have been compiled and transformed for the browser, including CSS.

Comment: @ThéoBenoit 
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "Firefox >= 63",
      "Chrome >= 55",
      "Safari >= 10",
      "Edge >= 80",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]

Comment: Yeah webpack do it of course. But you said : P.s. It would be great to avoid putting prefixes everywhere.

Comment: @ThéoBenoit I mean I would like to avoid using them manually.

Comment: I dont think the styling comes from Material UI itself, you should replicate your issue (without logic needed) on codesandbox to see if it works on both browsers